# Safari search suggestions do not appear when iOS restrictions are enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, search-engine

If I set Website Restrictions to *Limit Adult Content*, Safari stops showing search engine suggestions regardless of the engine being used (Bing, Yahoo, Google, or DuckDuckGo). If I change the setting back to *All Websites*, it starts working again. Search suggestions do show up if I make the query from the search engine's webpage.

I'm currently seeing this behavior on an iPhone 5S running iOS 11.2.6, but I've also seen it on other devices and OSs. If this is a known issue to Apple, I have yet to find a public statement about it.

How do I make search suggestions work when iOS restrictions are enabled?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You needed to spell it out for everyone because it was just a statement without any question.  See [ask] for tips on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering too so asked Apple Support and got a confirmation that this behavior is expected. In my opinion, it does not make sense to disable this feature since the suggestions still work in other app browsers. It only makes the Safari user experience worse.

Comment: Do you have a quote or a link? If so, could you [edit]] it into your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I can’t even find a history of the chat conversation with the apple safari support. You can ask them too. They response quickly.